# host proxying hotspot on rasberri pi b

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+, wireless, hotspot

I want to make my rasperry pi able to 1 host a wifi hotspot, with an external usb 2ndary wifi chip, and 2 redirect all clients through a socks5 proxy.

I want to host a hotspot using the integrated wifi chip, take the internet traffic of everyone connected, redirect them to a socks 5 proxy, and then send it to the local internet using a usb wifi chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly only certain USB devices work with the RPI..  Be sure to check that they will work before buying them.

Easiest method is to use the snap wifi-ap package it will allow you to setup a Wifi access point within minutes..

https://snapcraft.io/install/wifi-ap/raspbian

Then use wifi-ap.config and wifi-ap.status to configure your ESSID and pass-phrase etc.

DHCP can be used to redirect them to a proxy SOCK5 server.

If you want finer grain control (so I wanted to create a dual channel 2.4GHZ/5.0GHZ) for your access point then you will need to setup the different components independently which isn't too hard but for a simple setup wifi-ap is quick.

This is a good guide for setting up a Raspberry pi manually..
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wireless-access-point/

Probably not much use as you want todo custom features but there is a RaspAP install which turns your Raspberry PI into a fully featured access point.

https://raspap.com